# Laravel: Move the upload folder out of the public_html folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, file-structure

The structure of my project folder is as follows:

```
.
└── /home (Inaccessible)
    └── user
        └── public_html
            ├── app
            ┊
            ├── public
            │   ├── css
            │   ┊
            │   └── upload
            ┊
            ├── .htaccess
            └── .env
```

As you can see, the project upload folder is in the public folder, and the following code shows the specifications of my public disk:

```php
'disks' => [
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('upload'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/upload',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
]
```

And because my project is on a shared host, I added an .htaccess file with the following content to public_html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in the .env file I added the following line

```
ASSET_URL=/public
```

**Now** I want to move the upload folder out of public_html, I want the structure of the project folders to be as follows:

```
.
└── /home (Inaccessible)
    └── user
        ├── public_html
        └── upload
```

I did not get the answer by changing the root address of the public disk as follows, and when I try to display a photo, I get `404 error`.

```php
'root' => preg_replace("/^(.*\/).*$/", "$1" ,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/upload'
// OR
'root' => base_path('../upload')
//OR
'root' => dirname(__DIR__,2) . '/upload',
```

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**
The links to my files are like `http://example.com/upload/1611343402_Colors.png`

Comment: Could you share a bit more details about your shared hosting? Specifically, what kinda panel it uses, and if it's possible to change web root directly for your domains?

Comment: Btw, hosting your Laravel project inside public_html is very risky, as your `.env` might be exposed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361840/is-it-unsafe-to-keep-a-laravel-project-files-inside-public-html?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upload folder should be in /root/storage if you are using laravel.

See docs of the storage facade https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

It works this way. The command `Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');` will store the file on the disk "local" which is defined in the config file `/root/config/filesystems.php`. Thats where you tried to change the root paramter i guess. You can access any files from storage in your controller files, jobs and so on.

If you want to use the storage for public assets which need to be delivered by the web server you need to do the following:

Create a [symlink](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) between a folder `/root/public/storage` and `/root/storage/app/public`by using the shell command `php artisan storage:link`

[image]

This way you can use the storage helper like this `echo asset('storage/file.txt');` deliver the file `/root/storage/app/public/file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to allow direct access above public_html on a shared server, even if you really want to.

Here is a workaround: create a script that loads your images, then you can manipulate it in a secure way, while loading images from any directory.

The general way to do this is outlined here:
[Loading an image through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959131/loading-an-image-through-php)

Credit: joschua011

```
$img = 'path/to/image.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($img);
```

Other than that, there is no inherent problem with having images inside of the public folder, as long as you secure the folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to tell laravel to put your files there. You can easily set the root of your disk as the absolute path:

```
'root' => '/home/user/upload'
```

The problem is, apache2 is configured to only handle the files inside your `public_html` folder.

I would create a symlink between your `public_html/public/upload` folder and your actual `upload` folder.

```
ln -s /home/user/upload /home/user/public_html/public/upload
```

Next, be sure that the apache www-data user folder has the proper permission on the folder `/home/user/upload`

Now you can link the files in the same way as before to the public, while storing them on your custom folder